# Modify script to fire when keys are pressed at same time

Tags: autohotkey

Below is command I use to launch chrome :

```
:*:chr::   ;
Run www.google.com,
return
```

How can I modify this script so that chr is required to pressed at same time instead of succession so holding "chr" down launches chrome (pressing "chr" in succession should not launch chrome). ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to run the command when the keys c+h+r are pressed at the same time? Am I getting this right? 
If so, then this would probably be the way to go:

```
~c::
~h::
~r::
If (GetKeyState("c","p") && GetKeyState("h","p") && GetKeyState("r","p")) {
    Run www.google.com
}
Return
```